# Request results HTTP 200 with Firefox/Chrome but 403 with curl

Tags: http, curl, http-headers

I am trying to download a file from [this URL](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Edwin-Wang-6/publication/264488606_Human_Signaling_Network_Version_6/data/53e102ed0cf2235f35271ea3/HuamnSignalingNet-v6.csv?origin=publication_detail). If opened in a browser, it can be retrieved successfully (single request, no redirection, no cookies necessary). If I use the *copy as cURL* menu in the browser inspector and run the `curl` command, the request fails with HTTP 403. I captured both with Wireshark, with TLS decrypted, and so far I couldn't find the key difference. You can see the captures as plain text here:

- [Curl (HTTP 403)](http://ix.io/4sak)
- [Chromium (HTTP 200)](http://ix.io/4sal)

The outcome is already clear when the server sends the response headers, so I truncated the latter one to 5k lines.

Seemingly identical requests produce different outcomes for a number of reasons, e.g. if curl uses alpn, or openssl throws error at premature eof, etc. -- I would also appreciate such ideas from you about the potential reason, and of course anything that we can see in the outputs. Please let me know if I should provide the captures in better format, or gather more information.

Note: curl duplicates the `authority` header, but that's not the reason of the failure.

Comment: You should use stackoverflow’s image service. It allows you to press a button in the question editor and upload the image. It gets uploaded to i.stack.imgur.com, which is a more reputable website. I cannot access your image from where I am right now, and it is possible that your website may delete the image after a certain length of time, defeating the point of this question.

Comment: Thanks, but these are not images, but text in a pastebin kind of thing. I used this one (ix io) because it's super easy, though I'm happy to change to another one.

Comment: Why can’t you post them in stackoverflow? If you post in stackoverflow, in a code tag, it won’t take up the whole question

Comment: Hm, I am hesitant to post 2 x 5000 lines of tcp dump. Or is that a normal practice?

Comment: That is not normal. No one would have the time to look through all of that. Narrow it down to what is important. Posting it on a different website doesn't make it more convenient to read.

Comment: Have you got answer yet? I got the same problem: the GET request response 200 in browser but 403 with cURL while I'm using copy as cURL in Devtools. It's weird